# Can't get current user context in page panager

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, rng

I'm using page manger with panel, and Rng module.

I want a custom page for the registration page (the page to see the registrant information, provided by the Rng module) depending of the current user's role.

So i added a registration page with page manager with this path:

/registration/%

It work, but when i want to set the role has a selection criteria, it's not in the drop down, because there is no current user in the context.

How can i had the current user (not a specific user) in the context?

Comment: In the 'contexts' tab is Current User not in the dropdown next to 'add new context'?

Comment: No i haven't. I only had  "user" for adding specific user in the context, not the current one.

Comment: Is this Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And i'm answering myself, again:

it seem to be a bug in the alpha24.

I updated with the current dev version (2017-Jan-18), and now i've got the current user in the context, and in the criteria !